# How will a unique_ptr resource be freed after it is set to nullptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is this undefined behavior? How can it delete the resource allocated if the pointer points to nowhere?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
    public:
    A()  {std::cout << "ctor"<<std::endl;};
    ~A(){std::cout << "dtor"<<std::endl;};

};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
    ptr = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ctor
dtor
```

Perhaps it was created this way intentionally to solve some sort of problem?

Comment: Hmmm wut???????

Comment: The destructor is called here: `ptr = nullptr;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're calling the `std::unique_ptr` assignment operator (`operator=( nullptr_t )`). This operator deletes the currently owned object and sets the unique pointer to own nothing. If you want to release ownership of the object so it is not deleted, there is a function for that.

```
ptr.release();
```

> Perhaps it was created this way intentionally to solve some sort of problem?

Yes, it was designed to reduce instances of accidental memory leaks, by requiring you to be explicit when you want to release ownership of an object (via the release function).

Comment: Oh, I see. "You can accept an answer in 10 minutes" - s.o said. Makes a lot of sense to unique_ptr. Quite clarifies my doubt! Thanks

Comment: Why use a unique smart pointer if you allow access from outside as well (presumably after a release for sure)?

Comment: @Scooter: Is that question for me? Because I don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, for you. What is a use case for release()?

Comment: @Scooter juggling a dynamically-allocated object around before passing it to a non-smart API.

Comment: @Scooter If you want to transfer the managed object to a different smart pointer you might use `release()`